# Internal custom controls in XAML markup

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Why cannot I use custom control with "internal" access modifier from the same assembly? Is not it annoying? (.NET Framework 3.5)

Comment: Why can you do that? Would not it help you make public sealed class for component?

Comment: Could you provide more details? In generel the custom controls are in separate projects (WPF Custom Control Library) and as well their are built in separate assemblies so you wont see the internal members once using the control in your WPF project.

Comment: It is true for control libraries. But even in this case may be a small support controls that should not be visible from the outside. And the same small simple one time controls may exist in the main application. Why should they be "public"? Why "WindowMain" should be "public" (otherwise you can't bind to its properties, such as static RoutedUICommand properties and so on) after all?